# C# CimSession.TestConnection method not responding when host is offline

Tags: c#, wmi

I have a C# app which is using CimSession to periodically query PercentProcessorTime of a remote host.
Everything is working as expected until the remote host becomes offline. Then the app is just hanging.

I am using the CimSession.TestConnection method to check if the session is still valid. However the CimSession.TestConnection does not return anything if the host is offline. I would expect it to return false or throw an exception.

Here is the relevant part of the code.
The QueryMethod:

```
string Namespace = @"root\cimv2";
string OSQuery = $"SELECT PercentProcessorTime FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process WHERE Name LIKE '{processName}%'";

IEnumerable<CimInstance> queryInstance = mySession.QueryInstances(Namespace, "WQL", OSQuery);

foreach (CimInstance cimInstance in queryInstance)
{
    int currentValue = Convert.ToInt32(cimInstance.CimInstanceProperties["PercentProcessorTime"].Value);

                
    if (currentValue >= treshold)
    {
       currentCounter = 1;
    }
    break; 
}
```

And the method invocation:

```
if(mySession.TestConnection())
tempValue = QueryMethod(mySession);
```

How can I handle the situation when the host is offline?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you create the `CimSession` instance, pass a [`CimSessionOptions` value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.management.infrastructure.options.cimsessionoptions) with an appropriate `Timeout` set:

```cs
var options = new CimSessionOptions(){ Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) };

mySession = new CimSession("remoteMachineName", options);
```

Comment: That did the trick. Not sure how I forgot about this SessionOption. Anyway thank you very much!